# GEM Error - google-api-client-0.38.0 requires ruby version ~> 2.4, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 3.0.2p107

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, rubygems

When running  **bundle install** I was getting this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
google-api-client-0.38.0 requires ruby version ~> 2.4, which is incompatible
with the current version, ruby 3.0.2p107
```

Couldn't find a fix/reason, answer below (thought I'd post this to help someone else/took me a 1 hour to find a fix).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run (via Terminal) fixes it:

```
bundle update
```